# Losing quality after watermarking CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Users on my website can upload images. After resizing the images with Image_lib library (the banner has to be 500*200px), I put it into another blank image so it can be centered.

So I do that :

- image is resized to 500*200px
- if the new sizes are 500*180px for example, it is put into another blank image of sizes 500*200px

I works all fine with png images, but when I try with jpeg, there is a high lose of quality !

Here's the normal image :

```
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2013/45/1384054154-google-banniere.jpg
```

Here is the image watermarked :

```
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2013/45/1384054418-google-banniere.jpg
```

And this is my code to watermark :

```
$config['source_image'] = 'src/images/banner-blank.png'; // BLANK PNG IMAGE
$config['wm_overlay_path'] = $data['full_path']; // ACTUAL JPEG
$config['new_image'] = $data['full_path']; // SAVE PATH FOR THE NEW JPEG
$config['quality'] = '100%';
$config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
$config['wm_opacity'] = '100';
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';

$this->image_lib->initialize($config); 

if (!$this->image_lib->watermark()) 
{
    $error = array('response' => $this->image_lib->display_errors());
    echo json_encode($error);
    exit();
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm having a same issue :(